# Selenium Java error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my AUT, I've a button for generating OTP. Upon clicking on the button, OTP is generated and received on registered mobile.

But in my AUT, when the button is clicked; a new tab opens for 2 seconds. Control comes to the current page and simultaneously, the new tab is closed after 2 seconds. While automating with selenium, my script fails as soon as the second page opens.

Comment: Show us a code and exception that you received please.

Comment: Use getWindowHandle() method to handle the windows.